# Is there any way to remove italic effect <i> tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How do I remove italic effect of `<i>` tag so I can do this:

```
<span>
    test<i>test</i>
</span>
```

I am filling some text in the `<i>` tag using jQuery innerHtml, so it comes in italic, but I don't want the italic effect.

Is there any way I can remove the italic effect using CSS?

I cant use a different tag. I can only use the `<i>` tag.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You just need to use this CSS code:

```
.no-italics {
    font-style: normal;   
}
```

HTML code:

```
<span>
   test
   <i class='no-italics'>test</i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 19):

Use font-style:

```css
i {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do any formatting with CSS.

Like:

```
b {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

will change bold text to normal.

Similarly,

```
i {
    font-style: normal;
}
```

will make `<i>` font style as normal (non-italic).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the CSS style `font-style: normal` to get that effect.  Then you can do your jQuery to put text in the tag:

```js
$('i#replace').html('this text isn\'t italicized either . . . ');
```

```css
i {
  font-style: normal;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>text text <i id="replace">this is NOT italic</i> text text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `font-style` to reset the italic style when the class is used.

```css
i.no-italics {
    font-style: normal;   
}
```

```html
<i class="no-italics">Olmstead v. L.C. and E.W</i>
```