# how to remove the italic behaviour of font. If the button is TILT?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that if i skew the button to -15deg. Its tilt like itlaic font style but when the button tilt the text inside the button also got tilt(italic).

I want to know that how is it possible that if the button is tilt(italic)  then the text should be in normal font style.

now its showing like this [image: button with italic font] . I want button should be like this but text shouldn't be like this it should be normal.

i follow this answer but this is not working for me. [font style should be normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203574/is-there-any-way-to-remove-italic-effect-i-tag-using-css)

Is there any problem in my code below:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="BUTTON IS THIS">
```

**CSS:**

```
#btn{
background-color:#29b6f6;
color:#fff;
transform: skewX(-15deg);
font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `<button>BUTTON IS THIS</button>` instead; since you can then wrap the text inside with another tag and style that tag to give it a skew opposite of the one applied to the button itself; so it will look how you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skew element but keep text normal (unskewed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947565/how-to-skew-element-but-keep-text-normal-unskewed)

Comment: @IvanS95 u are right . gonna try this. Thanks

Comment: @IvanS95 Thanks dude. Your suggestion work :-)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a transformation to a nested element:

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" type="submit"><span>BUTTON IS THIS</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
#btn{
background-color:#29b6f6;
color:#fff;
transform: skewX(-15deg);
}
#btn span {
  display: block;
  transform: skewX(15deg);
}
```